# Ionic native google maps plugin doesn't show map after getRootNav().push()

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, resize, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 and working on iPhone 7 plus with iOS 11. I'm using the Ionic native google maps plugin (http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/). I have two sets of tabs (user/admin) and I need to switch between them with the following code:

```
  switch() {
    this.app.getRootNav().push(tabs2);
  }
```

If I've loaded the map on Tabs1 and then move to Tabs2 and back to Tabs1 and try to load the map again, it doesn't load and only shows white screen.

I've seen solutions for this in other posts, where it was advised to "resize" the map in order to load it with the following code:

`google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');`

As far as I know this is NOT the ionic native plugin (it's the JS web version). I'm having trouble in implement the same functionality with the native plugin. Or really any other solution will work just fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detach the map before going back to Tabs1 from Tabs2.

```
// Detach
this.map.setDiv(null);

// Attach again
this.map.setDiv(div);
```

If you create a demo project, and share it on github, I will check it.

Comment: thanks. One questions, in this.map.setDiv(div); what is "div" in the brackets?

Comment: I've got it like this: this.geocoding.map.setDiv(document.getElementById('map'));

Comment: But another question, until the page DOM is loaded, you can't get elements by ID. and I'm switching tabs from another page. So the mechanics is I need to leave the Map page to another page (same Tabs1), then switch to Tabs2 and then switch to Tabs1 (starting page which is NOT maps) and move to Maps pages (Tabs1). I'm testing out ionViewWillLeave() and ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: Tested both, this.geocoding.map.setDiv() doesn't execute on either leaving or entering the page... Also I forgot to mention that my GoogleMaps is done via an Ionic Provider, but that should really matter.

Comment: If you use `@ionic-native/google-maps@4.3.3` and specify the div id instead of div element, the plugin waits until the specified DOM is ready. By the way, you hide lots of things about your code. I only answers for the first question. If you want to ask me further, please ask at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues